# Need to expand the expandable listview which are opened before in Parent screen when click on goback() in child screen

Tags: react-native, expandablelistview, expandable

I have an expandable listview on the parent screen. I expanded listview to see subcategory items. Now I clicked on one subcategory, it will navigate another screen(child screen). when I click on goback() method in child screen the parent screen is displaying with a collapsed list view.

Need to expand the expandable listview in expand mode only which are opened before in Parent screen when clicking on goback() in child screen.

Please help me.

Comment: Please post the relevant code block and steps you have tried so far. Thanks

Comment: are you using react-native-router-flux?

Comment: @Riddhi i'm using react-native only

Comment: @SaachiTech posted code..Please check once

Comment: @Priyanka are you using react-navigation? which version? Also, please post how you have the stack set-up?

Comment: @SaachiTech didn't install any packager react-navigation in my project.

Comment: As per the document, once a stack screen mounted it will remain mounted and it will not refresh unless you explicitly refresh it using focus listener or redux state. You can read more about the lifecycle at https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-lifecycle. Saying that your accordion must remain open. Here is a simple snack with a minimal example which works the way you expect https://snack.expo.io/@saachitech/moving-between-screens-%7C-react-navigation

Comment: @satchi I saw the example which you provided and the navigation life cycle also.
Please check the updated code above. how can I expand the selected row when the screen navigates from child screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a parent screen name in the navigation to move from child to parent instead of goback().

Comment: in that case,screen will be refresh right...I don't wanna refresh the screen.Need display the expandable listview in expand mode only

Answer (score 0):

Use navigation.replace(routeName,params) to pass the selected list in child componentÏ instead of goBack.

Comment: how to pop the screen from child to parent screen without refresh the page.I'm new to react-native